# Is $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ a CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the structure of CW complex by considering lattices. What about $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb{R}{\infty}$? If you mean $\bigcup_n\Bbb{R}^n$, the answer is yes. If you mean an infinite product of copies of $\Bbb{R}$, I think the answer is probably no..

Comment: I mean $\cup_n \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View $\Bbb{R}^n$ as the set of sequences $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0, 0, \ldots)$, and make each $\Bbb{R}^n$ into a CW complex in such a way that $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a subcomplex of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. (The natural lattice construction will have this property.) The union of the cells in all the $\Bbb{R}^n$ gives a CW structure on $\bigcup_n\Bbb{R}^n$.