# Is there a set in which division of 0 by 0 is defined?

Tags: analysis, field-theory, infinity, binary-operations

The reason I ask this is that I've discovered that, even though they don't satisfy all field axioms, there are sets called projectively extended real number line and Riemann sphere, which are ℝ∪{∞} and ℂ∪{∞} where division of every nonzero number of the set by 0 is defined as ∞. However, the two sets' arithmetic operations aren't total and some operations are left undefined. These include: ∞+∞, ∞-∞, ∞·0, 0·∞, ∞/∞, and 0/0. My question is that if there is, or could be a field-like set that can also define the results of these operations. And could there be a logical definition for those operations, especially 0/0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach than that of the wheel structure(s) in [E. Joseph](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/288138/e-joseph)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3002357/26369) is given by considering the [linear/vector subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) of the plane (e.g. $\mathbb R^2$), regarded as [binary relations](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) and with appropriate [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)).

## Motivation

One way to look at numbers is as [linear operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map): The number $r$ corresponds to the function given by $f(x)=rx$. This gives us a new lens through which to examine things, especially multiplication and [multiplicative inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse).

Given $f(x)=rx$ and $g(x)=sx$, then $f\circ g$ sends $x$ to $(rs)x$, so multiplication arises as [composition of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). Similarly, for $r\ne0$, the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of $f(x)=rx$ would be $f^{-1}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)x$.

Both of these ideas can be understood in more generality as [composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) and [inverse relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) (sometimes called converse relations). So if we select a slightly broader class of relations than "1-d linear operators", we can embed the numbers in a larger structure. By thinking of the graphs of these operators/relations, one "broader class" would be all of the subspaces of the plane.

## Setup

#### Old and New Elements

For each number $r$, there is a corresponding subspace $[r]=\{(x,y)\mid y=rx\}$. So the numbers can be viewed as non-vertical lines through the origin with the number as its slope.

There are three other subspaces of the plane:

1. The vertical line $\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}$, which we will denote by $\infty$.
2. The origin $\{(0,0)\}$, which we will denote by $\bot$.
3. The whole plane, which we will denote by $\top$.

#### The operations

There are four particularly important operations on numbers: the [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) operations for [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse) ([aka](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AKA#Adverb) minus) and [reciprocals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse), and the [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) operations of addition and multiplication.

All of these can be understood in terms of the corresponding subspaces, without appealing to the nonlinear structure directly:

1. The negation of $[r]=\{(x,y)\mid y=rx\}$ should be $\{(x,y)\mid y=(-r)x\}$, which is $\{(x,y)\mid (x,-y)\in [r]\}$.
2. If $r\ne0$, the reciprocal of $[r]=\{(x,y)\mid y=rx\}$ should be $\{(x,y)\mid y=(r^{-1})x\}$, which is $\{(x,y)\mid (y,x)\in [r]\}$.
3. The sum of $[r]=\{(x,y)\mid y=rx\}$ and $[s]=\{(x,y)\mid y=sx\}$ should be $\{(x,y)\mid y=(r+s)x\}$, which is $\{(x,z)\mid \exists y_1,y_2: (x,y_1)\in [r] \land (x,y_2)\in [s]\land y_1+y_2=z\}$.
4. The product of $[r]=\{(x,y)\mid y=rx\}$ and $[s]=\{(x,y)\mid y=sx\}$ should be $\{(x,y)\mid y=(rs)x\}$, which is $\{(x,z)\mid \exists y: (x,y)\in [s] \land (y,z)\in [r]\}$ (the order is inspired by composing the linear functions).

But those latter characterizations work just as well for other relations, so we will take those as general definitions:

1. $-R=\{(x,y)\mid (x,-y)\in R\}$
2. $R^+=\{(x,y)\mid (y,x)\in R\}$ (we might call this [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse))
3. $R+S=\{(x,z)\mid \exists y_1,y_2: (x,y_1)\in R \land (x,y_2)\in S\land y_1+y_2=z\}$
4. $R*S=\{(x,z)\mid \exists y: (x,y)\in S \land (y,z)\in R\}$

In particular, we can look at $[0]^+$ (even though $\frac{1}{0}$ does not define a number) and evaluate any of these operations on the three subspaces that do not correspond to numbers.

## 0/0?

We have not defined division, but for numbers $r,s$ with $r\ne0$, $[s/r]=[s]*[r]^+=[r]^+*[s]$. Therefore, $0/0$ could be interpreted as either $[0]*[0]^+$ or $[0]^+*[0]$.

Note that $[0]^+=\infty$ (if you reflect a horizontal line about $y=x$ you get a vertical line), so the question reduces to the value(s) of $[0]*\infty$ and $\infty*[0]$.

For $[0]*\infty$, the only input $\infty$ allows is $0$ and the only output of $[0]$ is $0$, so this is just the origin: $\bot$.

For $\infty*[0]$, $[0]$ sends all inputs to $0$, and $\infty$ sends $0$ to all outputs, so this is the entire plane: $\top$.

## Operation Tables

For completeness, we can show all of the results of these operations. Below, $r$ and $s$ represent any nonzero number.

#### Negation

\begin{matrix}X: & [r] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\
-X: & [-r] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top
\end{matrix}

#### Pseudoinverse

\begin{matrix}X: & [r] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\
X^{+}: & [\frac{1}{r}] & \infty & 0 & \bot & \top
\end{matrix}

#### Addition

Note that addition of these subspaces is commutative since addition of numbers is:
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}+ & [s] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\\hline{}[r] & [r+s] & [r] & \infty & \bot & \top\\{}[0] & [s] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\\infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty\\\bot & \bot & \bot & \infty & \bot & \infty\\\top & \top & \top & \infty & \infty & \top\end{array}

#### Multiplication

Since Multiplication is not commutative, $R*S$ will be the entry with the row $R$ and column $S$:
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}
* & [s] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\\hline
[r] & [rs] & [0] & \infty & \bot & \top\\{}
[0] & [0] & [0] & \bot & \bot & [0]\\
\infty & \infty & \top & \infty & \infty & \top\\
\bot & \bot & [0] & \bot & \bot & [0]\\
\top & \top & \top & \infty & \infty & \top
\end{array}

## Source

None of these ideas are my own. I first saw this in the [Graphical Linear Algebra blog](https://graphicallinearalgebra.net/) (though there it's wrapped up with a discussion of, well, graphical linear algebra). The most relevant entry is [Keep Calm and Divide by Zero](https://graphicallinearalgebra.net/2015/12/14/26-keep-calm-and-divide-by-zero/), but the following two entries contain interesting context as well. Given his work on graphical linear algebra, this approach may have been discovered by [Paweł Sobociński](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Eps1a06/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a structure called a *wheel*, whose purpose is to define division by $0$. More specifically, there is $x/0$ for $x\ne 0$ and $0/0$ in a wheel, and those two elements are not the same.

It is used for formel computations in computers.

You can find more informations [there](https://www2.math.su.se/reports/2001/11/2001-11.pdf) (and how it is formally constructed).

Comment: Do wheels also have ∞+∞, ∞-∞, ∞·0, 0·∞, and ∞/∞ defined?

Comment: As you can see in the document, $1/0$ is denoted by $\infty$, but this is a formal construction. And $\infty/\infty=0/0$ which is denoted by $\perp$.

Comment: But is it possible to add 0/0 to itself or to subtract 0/0 from itself? The document is highly technical so it's very hard to understand.

Comment: @ozigzagor Yes it is.

Comment: As far as I understand, the value of ⊥ is unchangeable no matter what you do with arithmetic operations?

Comment: @ozigzagor I understand that too.