# Why infinities but not infinitesimals?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, infinitesimals

Why is the use of *infinities* generally accepted, but not the use of *infinitesimals*?

I know a little about non-standard analysis, but that seems to be the exception?  From what I've seen, usually infinitesimals are avoided elsewhere (and are replaced by the notion of a limit, which again is based on infinities) even when they are presented rigorously and clearly.

Is there a valid reason for this (beyond simple preference)?

Comment: It is very easy to see that if you claim to have a largest number, I can add one to it to show that it cannot be. It is very difficult to imagine a smallest positive number for the a similar reason: I can take half.

Comment: Infinitesimals make ordered fields non-Archimedian, which is a vital property of the real numbers for calculating limits.

Comment: In real analysis, infinity comes up in the sense of things tending to infinity, which is just the convenient shortcut for describing that they grow arbitrarily large. On the other hand, when something grows arbitrarily small (in the sense of absolute value), that means it tends to $0$, precisely because the real numbers are Archimedian. So the question really is what the "use of infinitesimals" would be, since there doesn't seem to be a natural thing in real analysis that could be described as infinitesimal and if you start to axiomatize infinitesimals, you end up doing non-standard analysis.

Comment: @Thorgott I see, so there is no useful way of rigorously using infinitesimals outside of non-standard analysis?

Comment: Because "adding" $\pm\infty$ to ${\mathbb R}$ deals with two natural special "processes", while inventing "infinitesimals" adds more artificial elements to ${\mathbb R}$ than there are atoms in the universe, just to avoid $\epsilon/\delta$-thinking.

Comment: I don't feel qualified to make such an absolute claim, but I certainly don't know of any way and the most natural interpretation as above just reduces to a trivial case. I'm rather trying to say that the "use of infinitesimals" isn't "not accepted", but that there just hardly seems to be any (in real analysis, that is).

Comment: Infinities appear in much more basic parts of mathematics (set theory) as the size of certain sets. It is really difficult to avoid. Infinitesimals are entirely possible to avoid. Maybe this difference in necessity that makes people more comfortable dealing with infinities than infinitesimals?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why infinitesimals are avoided. Differentials are used in calculus all the time. You can rigorously define how infinitesimals work,  it's just that people abuse them in contexts where rigor fails.

Comment: Actually "infinity" is not defined in real analysis. "Infinite set" is defined, certainly. But things like $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ do not use a previously defined notion of infinity. It's just notation.

Comment: @zhw. How do you use the concept of infinite sets without the concept of infinity?

Comment: @AlexR. Hum, the way I learnt calculus was with the idea that differentials were "sufficiently small" quantities, but not "infinitesimally" so.

Comment: @zhw. I don't think it's just notation, since at least one definition of this expression involves infinite sequences.

Comment: Thanks for these comments, I think I'm starting to understand why.

Comment: You can work with the definition $x\to \infty$ without defining $\infty$ as a stand alone definition.

Comment: @zhw. That's beside the point, though. If you're using notions such as infinite sets, then you've at least accepted the idea of infinite, I'd say (without necessarily having a formal definition of it).  This is not the case of infinitesimals, which was, at least in my undergraduate and postgraduate studies, avoided, and only mentioned when ridiculizing the idea.

Comment: Accepting infinite sets is a far cry from accepting infinity as a numerical concept. We go to great pains in Calculus to explain to students that "infinity arithmetic" is fraught with dangers like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\infty-\infty$. So I would not say that the use of infinities is generally accepted *in real analysis*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tough question that's hard to answer definitively because of the different "infinities" (for an overview, see [Understanding infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071681/26369)), the history and popularity of different branches of math involved, etc.

I think a large portion of the reasons come down to the fact that there are more contexts in which "infinities" would be useful than "infinitesimals". This has knock-on effects for, say, how math curricula are designed in universities, the level of general awareness of mathematicians which affects their ability to spread ideas, etc.

---

### Infinitesimals don't arise in common contexts

[Ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) were discovered when Cantor was working on real analysis, and [cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) (especially the [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)-uncountable distinction) are often useful when dealing with infinite sets, both in and outside of analysis. And $\pm\infty$ in [the extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) help to give a tidy account of limits and [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)). And if we broaden out view to complex analysis, the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) is fundamental and has a point labeled $\infty$. But none of these contexts directly lend themselves to an infinitesimal.

For ordinals and cardinals, we don't even have something positive but less than $1$. And for the others, an infinitesimal would break the (Dedekind) [completeness property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) of the reals that is critical for usual analysis to work.

### and their use is limited

Now, you *can* change the arithmetic on the ordinals to get the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number), or look at other [non-archimedean fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field), perhaps in a more general/abstract way. But these are not often useful for analysis purposes. In [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory), there are infinitesimals like "[up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory#Up)" that don't reside in a field, but that's a pretty niche area/application.

#### except maybe in nonstandard analysis

Arguably the most useful example of infinitesimals would be in [Robinson's hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) for [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis). In the scheme of things, this is relatively new in Calculus (so it's unfamiliar to many teachers and students would still have to learn standard approaches to connect with other material), and doesn't give you any new theorems about analysis, so it's tough to introduce into a curriculum. It's also arguably harder to make fully formal than a traditional construction of the reals.

That said, some mathematicians *are* using nonstandard analysis in their arguments. For example, [Terry Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao) has [a number of blog posts](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/nonstandard-analysis/) about it.

Comment: Much appreciated!  This is the kind of explanation I was hoping to get (but didn't expect to).  I'll take the time to go through your recommendations - they seem quite interesting.

Comment: @Stephen One thing I didn't think to mention in my answer is [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis) which uses a different concept of "infinitesimal" than "positive but less than 1/n for any positive integer n". But it is based on [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) and has theorems that can be phrased in ways that look wrong to people used to more conventional analysis, so it's also pretty niche.