# What's the cardinality of the infinity introduced in Riemann sphere model?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

In the Riemann sphere model, people extend the complex plane with a point at infinity: $\mathbb {C} \cup \{\infty \}$ and claim this expression: $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$.

I'm confused with what is this $\infty$. Is it a member of $\{\aleph_n\}$ numbers?
When we study infinities, we usually discuss cardinality. Does this $\infty$ corresponds to something's cardinality?

Comment: In response to the edit, I don't think I would agree that "we usually discuss cardinality" when we discuss infinity. People often discuss things like ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}a_n$, too. For a list of at least ten different concepts associated with infinity (of which cardinality is just one), see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3506355/26369) to the MathSE question [Understanding Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071681/26369).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it has a cardinality?

No. The $\infty$ there doesn't represent a particular set (though you might have to encode it as a set if you're using [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) as your [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics)), nor the cardinality of a particular set.

> What's the property of this infinity?

The properties are discussed throughout the English Wikipedia article for "[Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)". Is there a particular property you have a question about?